# Binary addition algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to implement a code from a standard quotient and remainder algorithm namely:

```
function divide(x,y)
   if x=0: return (q,r)=(0,0)
   (q,r)=divide(floor(x/2),y)
   q=2*q, r=2*r
   if x is odd: r=r+1
   if r>=y: r=r-y, q=q+1
   return (q,r)
```

with a c++ code here is the relavent part of my function

```
bool compareVector(const vector<int> &A, const vector<int> &B){
   if(A.size()<B.size())
      return(1==0);
   if(A.size()>B.size())
      return(1==1);
   for(int i=A.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
      if (A[i]>B[i])
         return(1==1);
      if(A[i]<B[i])
         return(1==0);
      }
   return(1==1);
}

struct QandR{
vector<int> r;
vector<int> q;
};


QandR Division(vector<int> BinaryA, const vector<int> & BinaryB, QandR &x){
   vector<int> one, zero;
   one.clear();
   one.push_back(1);
   zero.clear();
   zero.push_back(0);

   if(BinaryA==zero){
     return x;
   }
   else if(BinaryA==one){
      BinaryA[0]=0;
   }
   else if(BinaryA.size()>1)
      pop_front(BinaryA);
   x=Division(BinaryA,BinaryB,x);
   x.q=addBinary(x.q,x.q);
   x.r=addBinary(x.r,x.r);
   if(BinaryA[0]==1)
      x.r=addBinary(x.r,one);
   if(compareVector(x.r,BinaryB))
   {
      x.r=Subtract(x.r,BinaryB);
      x.q=addBinary(x.q,one);
   }
      return x;
}
```

However this simply does not work for example with BinaryA={1,0,1,1} and BinaryB={0,1}.  This is 13/2 so q should be {0,1,1}, and r should be {1}.  But my code out puts r={1} and q={0,1}.  I don't understand what is going on.  All functions that are used above that are not defined work.  Also,  is there a easier way to return two values in c++ if there is I would be grateful to know. Thank you.

Add is the whole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //this is only used for the user to insert a number
#include <stdlib.h> //this is used to convert the user iputed string to a vector
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void CleanArray(vector<int> & Array){           //CleanArray() is mainly for the Multiply function where we need to keep removing the enteries 
   for(int i=0;i<Array.size();i++){ 
      Array[i]=0;         //of a vector<int> Array. And then I clean some of the other struct vector<int>'s for saft
}

}






    vector<int> addBinary(vector<int> A,vector<int> B){             //addBinary() adds two struct vector<int>'s and returns a new struct vector<int>
        vector<int> C;      // C is our carry array but we take advantage of the fact that after we carry to a new column we nolonger need the old one so we 
            // can also use C to store our answere.

        C.assign(A.size()+1,0);
        CleanArray(C);
        for(int i=0; i<B.size();i++){       //Case 1 we are adding the first part where we are adding columns and we still have vector<int> A and vector<int> B
            if(C[i]+B[i]+A[i]==3){  
                C[i]=1;
                C[i+1]=1;
            }
            else if(B[i]+A[i]+C[i]==2){ 
              C[i]=0;   
             C[i+1]=1;
            }
            else if(B[i]+ A[i]+C[i] ==1){
                C[i]=1; 
                 }


        }

        for(int i=B.size();i<A.size();i++){ //Case 2 we adding where vector<int> B has been exasted and we only have vector<int> A and vector<int> C.
            if(C[i]+A[i]==2){
             C[i]=0;
                C[i+1]=1;
            }
            else if(A[i]==1){
                C[i]=1;
            }
       } //                    this is fine but not necessary. 

    if(C[C.size()-1]==0)    // We want to change C's member length_a if the aswere is one bigger then the size of A.size().  
       C.pop_back();
        return C;
    }

    vector<int> Subtract(vector<int> A, vector<int> B){             // this function is almost exactly the same as Multiply() using a vector<int> C to hold the value of A-B
        vector<int> C;
        C.assign(A.size(),0);
        CleanArray(C);
    //   reverse(B.begin(), B.end());
       for(int i=A.size()-B.size();i>0;i--)
          B.push_back(0);
    // reverse(B.begin(), B.end());
        for(int i=A.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            if((A[i]+B[i])==2)
                C[i]=0;
            else if(A[i]==1 && B[i]==0)
                C[i]=1;
            else if(B[i]==1 && A[i]==0){
                C[i]=1;
                int j=0;
                int k=i+1;
                while(j==0){            //we need this while loop bc when we have 0-1 this changes all values of 
                    if(C[k]==1){        //C[i+1] to the next C[]==1, changing all of those to 1 so ex 1000-1=0111
                        C[k]=0;
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if(C[k]==0){
                        C[k]=1;
                        k++;
                    }   
    //              if(i==C.size()-1 && C.size()>1) // this removes the zero's in front of the numberso the answer is not like 001 but 1. 
      //             C.pop_back();  
                }
            }
        //  else           this was the problem with subtraciton 
        //      C[i]=0;   ""   "    "     "     "         "
        }  
       int i=C.size()-1;
       while(C[i]==0 && i!=0){
          C.pop_back();
          i--;
       }

        return C;
    }




    vector<int> Multiply(const vector<int> & A, const vector<int> &B){ // This also uses the concept of having a vector<int> C to store the values of the succesive additions of the rows
        vector<int> C;
        C.assign(A.size(),0);
        for(int j=0;j<B.size();j++){
          vector<int> D;
          D.assign(A.size(),0);
            for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
             if(B[j]==1)                    
                    D[i]=A[i];
               // this makes a new row if B[j]==1 so if 1110101*1=1110101(0...0) there are j zero's in
          }
          D.insert(D.begin(),j,0); 
            C=addBinary(D,C);           //this adds the pervious value of C with the next row.
       }      
         return C;

    }


    void pop_front(vector<int> & A){

       reverse(A.begin(),A.end());
       A.pop_back();
       reverse(A.begin(),A.end());

    }

    bool compareVector(const vector<int> &A, const vector<int> &B){
       if(A.size()<B.size())
          return(1==0);
       if(A.size()>B.size())
          return(1==1);
       for(int i=A.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
          if (A[i]>B[i])
             return(1==1);
          if(A[i]<B[i])
             return(1==0);
          }
       return(1==1);
    }

    struct QandR{
    vector<int> r;
    vector<int> q;
    };


    QandR Division(vector<int> BinaryA, const vector<int> & BinaryB, QandR &x){
       vector<int> one, zero;
       one.clear();
       one.push_back(1);
       zero.clear();
       zero.push_back(0);

       if(BinaryA==zero){
         return x;
       }
       else if(BinaryA==one){
          BinaryA[0]=0;
       }
       else if(BinaryA.size()>1)
          pop_front(BinaryA);
       x=Division(BinaryA,BinaryB,x);
       x.q=addBinary(x.q,x.q);
       x.r=addBinary(x.r,x.r);
       if(BinaryA[0]==1)
          x.r=addBinary(x.r,one);
       if(compareVector(x.r,BinaryB))
       {
          x.r=Subtract(x.r,BinaryB);
          x.q=addBinary(x.q,one);
       }
          return x;
    }


    /*
    vector<int> modexp(vector<int> x,vector<int> y, vector<int> N){
       vector<int> one;
       vector<int> r;
       vector<int> q;
       one.push_back(0);
       if(y.size()==1 && y[1]==0)
          return one;
       y.pop_back();
       vector<int> z=modexp(x,y,N);
       if(y[0]==1){
          vector<int> D=Multiply(z,z);
          Division(D,N,q,r);
          z=q;
          return z;
       }
       else{
          vector<int> C =Multiply(Multiply(z,z),x);
          Division(C,N,q,r);
          z=q;
          return z;
       }

    }
    */
    int main(){

       int arraya[4]={1,1,0,1};
       int arrayb[2]={1,1};
       vector<int> a(arraya,arraya+4);
       vector<int> b(arrayb,arrayb+2);
       for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
          cout<<a[i]<<" ";
       }
       cout<<endl;
       pop_front(a);
       for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
          cout<<a[i]<<" ";
       cout<<endl;
       QandR x;
       x.r.clear();
       x.q.clear();
       x.r.push_back(0);
       x.q.push_back(0);
       x=Division(a,b,x); 
       for(int i=0;i<x.r.size();i++){
          cout<<x.r[i]<<" ";
       }
       cout<<endl;
       for(int i=0;i<x.q.size();i++)
          cout<<x.q[i]<<" ";
       cout<<endl;
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How is that A={1, 0, 1, 1} becomes 11 but B={0, 1} becomes 2?

Comment: They are in binary.

Comment: I know but shouldn't A be 13?

Comment: im just saying the remainder should be 1. And the quotient should be 6

Comment: yes that was a typo

Comment: Can you please post the code for addBinary, pop_front and Subtract? I know perhaps they are trivial but it is safer to check them as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156496/discussion-between-a-mashreghi-and-riemann-bitcoin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide BinaryA by 2, and try to call Division again, you have to return BinaryA to its original state so that you can verify if it was odd or not. 
So, in these two cases:

```
else if(BinaryA==one){
BinaryA[0]=0;
}
else if(BinaryA.size()>1)
pop_front(BinaryA);'
```

you have to keep the bit that is lost and restore it after the recursive Division has returned.